# iPhone 2G error "USB Device Not Recognized" on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, iphone

When I connect my iPhone 2G to my PC, I get the following error:

> USB Device Not Recognized

Looks like the PC does not recognize my iPhone.

What do I have to do? I have re-installed iTunes, but unfortunately the problem is not resolved.

Comment: Try plugging it to a different port?

Comment: Also, make sure it's a direct connection to the PC USB port, and not through some hub or extension.

Comment: Details on the PC?  how old?  you may want to check the solutions suggested in other USB questions eg http://superuser.com/questions/50118/why-do-i-get-usb-device-not-recognized

Comment: Great excuse to get an iPhone 4!

Answer (score 1):

If you've tried jailbreaking you're Ipod may be in recovery mode or something. Try taking out of it by pressing and holding the power + home buttons for 20 seconds then releasing the home button and hold the power button for another 10 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

You need to try it on a different computer to tell if the problem is the iPhone itself or the PC.

You might also want to try another USB sync cable, since that is a variable as well. There have been reports of iPhone cables going bad.

Answer (score 1):

Your data cable might be damaged and need repair or replacement.

Test this with a friend's data cable if you can get access to one. If so, then there's your problem and you'll just need a new one.

Answer (score 1):

I connected my USB cable to the PC, but not to my phone. Then I played a video and pressed the button while inserting the USB cable into the phone.

Fixed it in my case without an error. Just play a video and plug the cable as soon as you close the video by pressing button.